# Module/code to automatically generate an id number for title of page

Tags: 7

I want to automatically generate a project id. (To go where the title would go on a drupal webpage)

I am guessing this might be possible with php? But i don't know whether it is possible to do it for a title because I have only managed to acheive php in the code.

I want the title to identify a project and each project to have sub cases (also with unique identifiers).

I don't want the number to be randomly generated but rather it have some attributes that can be used to determine characteristics about the project.

Ideally, I want t end up with an id which is something like this eg

```
 Ldn101201
```

where 
ldn is the city 10 is the start month 12 is the start year and 01 is the project number.

Ldn will be inserted because the user opening the project is based in london 
1012 will be inserted because this was the date when the project was made
and the last number will be the generated number tagged on.

I really would be happy if I can at least get an ascending ids for when projects are created but if anyone has ideas about the more complicated part that would be great help also.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module? From the description:

> "auto_nodetitle" is a small and efficient module that allows hiding of
>   the content title field in the form. To prevent empty content title
>   fields one can configure it to generate the title by a given pattern.
>
> When the token module is installed it's possible to use various node
>   data for the auto generated title - e.g. use the text of a CCK field
>   (since 5.x).
>
> Advanced users can also provide some PHP code, that is used for
>   automatically generating an appropriate title.

Comment: Awesome. I will try this now.

Comment: Thanks! And, if it works for you, please remember to mark this answer as correct.

Comment: I checked and it worked. I had to install [entitylabel ]http://drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel and [token] http://drupal.org/project/token too

Comment: Token is a great module for many different integrations, like Rules, Page Title, Pathauto and anything else where you want to put snippets about a node/user/entity into a pattern.